# Easy way to create author account on node creation?

Tags: nodes

Is there an easy way to add a field that will automatically create an account for the author with the specified email address if that address doesn't exist? I have to enter information for new and old users on occasion and it would help if I could just type the e-mail address each time, instead of creating an account manually first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily using Rules Module. Just trigger a rule that whenever you create a node of the particular type, the Rule checks the entered email-id in the field and creates a new account using that email-id if it doesn't already exist.